# ignore method params from apache CXF javatowsdl generation

Tags: cxf

```
@POST
@Path("/version")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public final void testPost(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response, @Context final UriInfo uriInfo, @HeaderParam("xyz") final String user, final InputStream input){ }
```

generated WADL:

```
<request> 
  <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
  <param name="xyz" style="header" type="xs:string"/> 
  <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
</request>
```

I see the "representation" is getting generated in WADL for both "input" and "response".

1. I don't want "representation" for "@Suspended AsyncResponse response".
2. Also i dont want "param" tag for "HeaderParam("xyz") final String user".

Is there a way to ignore method params from WADL?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to customise WADL generation, you need this dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Than you can use annotations to customise your generation. But still you cannot ignore parameters. Here is an example from cxf documentation

```
@POST
@Path("books/{bookid}")
@Descriptions({ 
   @Description(value = "Adds a new book", target = DocTarget.METHOD),
   @Description(value = "Requested Book", target = DocTarget.RETURN),
   @Description(value = "Request", target = DocTarget.REQUEST),
   @Description(value = "Response", target = DocTarget.RESPONSE),
   @Description(value = "Resource", target = DocTarget.RESOURCE)
})
public Book addBook(@Description("book id") @PathParam("id") Long id, @Description("New Book") Book book) {...}
```

There is an other way but it not documented well. You can use [ElementClass](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-CustomizingWADLGeneration) annotation to modify request and response representation. Although there is no example usage, I hope it will work for you.